# How to define parameter of words?

Tags: bash, awk

What I trying to do is getting 2 string before and after of each characters.

Input file:

```
hello

reader

.....
```

The expected output is:

```
# # h e l //before character h is null and assign with '#". After character h are "e" and "l".
# h e l l //before character e is "h". After character e are "l" and "l".
h e l l o //before character l are "h" and "e". After character l are "l" and "o".
e l l o # //before character l are "e" and "l". After character l is "o".
l l o # # //before character o are "l" and "l". After character o is null and assign with '#".

# # r e a
# r e a d
r e a d e
e a d e r
a d e r #
d e r # #
```

Here is code: credit to RudiC

```
awk '
        { L = length * 2
          M = int (L / 4)
          X = sprintf ("%*sY%*s", M, "", M, "")
          gsub (/ /, "#", X)
          sub (/Y/, $1, X)
          gsub (/./, "& ", X)
          for (i=1; i<=L; i+=2) print substr (X, i, L-1)
        }
' $1
```

but the first word only working

```
# # h e l
# h e l l
h e l l o
e l l o #
l l o # #
# # # r e a
# # r e a d
# r e a d e
r e a d e r
e a d e r #
a d e r # #
```

Comment: Why does the expected output for the input line containing `reader` start with `# # r e a` instead of `# # r e a d`? Why wouldn't you expect to get a line containing `r e a d e r` in your output?

Comment: I would like to get only 2 strings before and after of each characters. In this case `"r e a d e r"`; first character is `"r"` before `r` is null thus assign with "#" and after `r` are `e` and `a`.

Comment: There's some crucial part of your explanation I'm just not getting. You say you want to get 2 strings before and after each character so why wouldn't you .... oh, hang on. I think I get it now, I thought you were left-shifting the characters on each row starting with 2 before the first character (for whatever reason) so I was looking at rows and wondering why `hello` appears in the middle row as I expected but not `reader`  when I should be looking at columns. Now that I see both `hello` and `reader` down the middle columns of your output it all make sense.

Comment: yes @EdMorton. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the length of the output should not be dependent on the length of the line read.

Give a try to this:

```
awk '
 {
    L = length($0) * 2
    M = int (L / 4)
    X = sprintf ("%*sY%*s", M, "", M, "")
    gsub (/ /, "#", X)
    sub (/Y/, $0, X)
    gsub (/./, "& ", X)
    for (i=1; i<=L; i+=2) print substr (X, i, (2*maxlen)-1)
 } ' maxlen=5 "${1}"
```

`maxlen=5` is used to pass parameter to `awk`. `awk` automatically detects if a parameter is `variable=value` or a `filename`. Use it to set the number of non space chars printed to standard output.

The test:

```
$ cat file
hello


reader
wonderful

$ awk '
{
  L = length($0) * 2
  M = int (L / 4)
  X = sprintf ("%*sY%*s", M, "", M, "")
  gsub (/ /, "#", X)
  sub (/Y/, $0, X)
  gsub (/./, "& ", X)
  for (i=1; i<=L; i+=2) print substr (X, i, (2*maxlen)-1)
} ' maxlen=5 file
# # h e l
# h e l l
h e l l o
e l l o #
l l o # #
# # # r e
# # r e a
# r e a d
r e a d e
e a d e r
a d e r #
# # # # w
# # # w o
# # w o n
# w o n d
w o n d e
o n d e r
n d e r f
d e r f u
e r f u l
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But now I have problem with long words. For example `"wonderful"`. it appear until character `e`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't do that, imagine what it'd do if `Y` appeared in the input or `$1` contained an `&`. See [@fedorqui's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37459398/1745001) for the right approach (best I can tell!).

Answer (score 4):

I would use something like this:

```
awk '{n=length($0)                    # get the length N of the string
      $0 = "##" $0 "##"               # prepend and append "##"
      gsub(/./, "& ")                 # add a space after every character
      for (i=1; i<=2*n; i+=2)         # loop X from position 1 to length of the string
          print substr($0, i, 5*2-1)  # print 5*2 chars from position 2X (-1 for the trailing space)
      print ""}' file                 # print an empty line to separate blocks
```

See it in action:

```
$ awk '{n=length($0); $0 = "##" $0 "##"; gsub(/./, "& "); {for (i=1; i<=2*n; i+=2) print substr($0, i, 5*2)} print ""}' file
# # h e l
# h e l l
h e l l o
e l l o #
l l o # #

# # r e a
# r e a d
r e a d e
e a d e r
a d e r #
d e r # #
```

As you see, the key here is to hardcode the number of characters you want to print instead of relying on the length of the string. In my case, I set it to 5.

Comment: I think you could clean it up a bit by getting rid of the 'n=length($0)' since it's only used once and instead have 'for (i=1; i<=2*length; i+=2)' other than that nice code.

Comment: @dood thanks! Note I store `length($0)` because later on I change `$0`'s value. I could say `i<=2*(length($0-4))` but it gets quite ugly : )

Comment: Ah, I see, yes in that case I think your original version is quite nice.

Comment: You also never want to call a function every time through a loop when it's value shouldn't change so setting a variable once before the loop is a much better approach. Change the substr length value to `substr($0, i, 5*2-1)` to avoid printing the undesirable blank character at the end of every line. and move the `length()` call to after the gsub() so you don't need to multiply n by 2 in the loop. I still have no idea why 5 is the magic number and `r e a d e r` shouldn't appear in the output though :-(.

Comment: @EdMorton yes... but if I move `length()` to after surrounding `$0` with "##" and then using `gsub()`, I need to use `for (i=1; i<=n-6; i+=2)`. That is, length - 4 times # - 2 extra spaces gotten from the gsub.

Comment: `n=length()-6; for (i=1; i<=n; i+=2)`. You could've just done `n=length()*2` though so whatever...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a 1-liner:

```
$ cat data 
hello
reader
$ sed 's/^/##/;s/$/##/' data | while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do for i in $(seq 0 $((${#line}-4))); do temp="${line:$i:5}"; [[ "${#temp}" -eq 5 ]] && echo "${line:$i:5}"; done; done | sed 's/./& /g'
# # h e l 
# h e l l 
h e l l o 
e l l o # 
l l o # # 
# # r e a 
# r e a d 
r e a d e 
e a d e r 
a d e r # 
d e r # #
```

subtracting 4 is to exclude the `#` which were added by `sed`.

Some linebreaks for better readability:

```
$ sed 's/^/##/;s/$/##/' data | while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
> for i in $(seq 0 $((${#line}-4))); do
> temp="${line:$i:5}"
> [[ "${#temp}" -eq 5 ]] && echo "${line:$i:5}"
> done
> done | sed 's/./& /g'
```

Using the same logic posting an awk solution for completeness:

```
$ cat data 
hello
reader
$ awk '{$0="##" $0 "##"; for(i=0;i<=(length($0)-4);i++) { temp=substr($0, i, 5); if(length(temp)==5) { gsub(/./, "& ", temp); print temp; }}}' data 
# # h e l 
# h e l l 
h e l l o 
e l l o # 
l l o # # 
# # r e a 
# r e a d 
r e a d e 
e a d e r 
a d e r # 
d e r # #
```

Here is the `awk` script:

```
{
    $0="##" $0 "##";
    for(i=0;i<=(length($0)-4);i++)
    {
        temp=substr($0, i, 5);
        gsub(/./, "& ", temp);
        if(length(temp)==10)
            print temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: pushing `one liner` there

Comment: @123 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean you are pushing the limit of what can be considered a one liner, This could easily be a small script.

Comment: @123 yeah right :P .. btw just wondering .. why isnt it allowed to have length and substring in a single parameter substitution like this:  `${#var:0:2}`

Comment: Why would you want to? What behaviour would you expect from that ?

Comment: @123 I was earlier trying to combine line 3 and 4 into a single line without the need of `temp` variable

Comment: I believe you can only have one parameter expansion use per variable. It's probably this way as there would have to be some logic to decide which expansion took priority. For example initially i thought that you were trying to take a substring of the length of variable.

Comment: @123 yeah right .. that makes sense .. it wouldn't work without prioritization

Answer (score 0):

Solution using awk and sed

```
sed 's/^/##/;s/$/##/' input.txt | awk '{ for(i = 1; i < length-3; i++) print substr($0, i, 5) }' | sed 's/./& /g'
```

Output

```
# # h e l 
# h e l l 
h e l l o 
e l l o # 
l l o # # 
# # r e a 
# r e a d 
r e a d e 
e a d e r 
a d e r # 
d e r # #
```

Comment: You never need sed if you're using awk.

Comment: @EdMorton Sure, but this is short, simple, and works.

Comment: `awk '{$0="##"$0"##"; for (i...}'`, for example, is shorter, simpler, more efficient and would also work.

Comment: @EdMorton Yup, I saw that solution and like it better as well.