# Getting 3 string before and after of each characters using awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

What I have expected is the output like below:

> [before character h is null and assign with '#". After character h
> are "e","l","l".]
>
> [before character e is "h". After character e are
> "l","l","o".]
>
> [before character l are "h" and "e". After character l
> are "l" and "o".]
>
> [before character l are "h" and "e". After character
> l are "l" and "o".]
>
> [before character l are "h","e","l". After
> character l is "o".]
>
> [before character o are "e","l","l". After
> character o is null and assign with '#".]

```
# # # h e l l  
# # h e l l o  
# h e l l o #  
h e l l o # #  
e l l o # # # 

# # # w o n d
# # w o n d e
# w o n d e r
w o n d e r f
o n d e r f u
n d e r f u l
d e r f u l #
e r f u l # #
r f u l # # #
```

Input file:

```
h e l l o

w o n d e r f u l
```

Code:

```
awk -v s1="# # #" 
'BEGIN{v=length(s1)}
      {$0=s1 $0 s1;num=split($0, A,"");
         for(i=v+1;i<=num-v;i++){
            q=i-v;p=i+v;
         while(q<=p){
            Q=Q?Q OFS A[q]:A[q];q++
         };
      print Q;Q=""
      }
}' InputFile
```

But the result I got is:

```
#   #   # h   e   l  
  #   # h   e   l   l
#   # h   e   l   l  
  # h   e   l   l   o
# h   e   l   l   o #
h   e   l   l   o #  
  e   l   l   o #   #
e   l   l   o #   #  
  l   l   o #   #   #

#   #   # w   o   n  
  #   # w   o   n   d
#   # w   o   n   d  
  # w   o   n   d   e
# w   o   n   d   e  
w   o   n   d   e   r
  o   n   d   e   r  
o   n   d   e   r   f
  n   d   e   r   f  
n   d   e   r   f   u
  d   e   r   f   u  
d   e   r   f   u   l
  e   r   f   u   l #
e   r   f   u   l #  
  r   f   u   l #   #
r   f   u   l #   #  
  f   u   l #   #   #
```

How to solve it? Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: I did slightly better by setting OFS to "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `gsub(/ /,"")` to the top of [@fedorqui's answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37459398/1745001), change `##` to `###` and change `5` to `7` and you get:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/ /,"")
    n=length($0)
    $0 = "###" $0 "###"
    gsub(/./, "& ")
    for (i=1; i<=2*n; i+=2)
        print substr($0, i, 7*2-1)
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
# # # h e l l
# # h e l l o
# h e l l o #
h e l l o # #
e l l o # # #


# # # w o n d
# # w o n d e
# w o n d e r
w o n d e r f
o n d e r f u
n d e r f u l
d e r f u l #
e r f u l # #
r f u l # # #
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Morton.

Comment: You're welcome. You really should have selected @fedorqui's answer to your previous question, it was by far the clearest and simplest and that, as you have now discovered, is extremely important if/when you need to tweak it when your requirements change. I'm sure you could have tweaked that as I did and not have had to ask for help.